# Is there an easier way to test PHP source-code on multi-platforms using Docker images?

Tags: docker, testing, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-image

I'm performing security testing on PHP source-code. The functionality of the script highly depends on the underlying infrastructure since it has optimizations for Linux, OSx and Windows as well as PHP 5.x, PHP 7.x, MySQL 4.x and 5.x. Also there is a possibility to use a different database back-end like SQLite.

I wrote some good tests in order to test specific functionality. And I want to reuse that test and automatically run my tests in the different environments. I would like to use Docker for that. But I'm quite new to Docker. Although I'm pretty handy in Bash scripting. I did some research into existing containers and possibilities. But it seems there is no easy way to get the desired containers.

Let's for now forget about OSx and Windows, and focus on Linux only. To make things easier. In my ideal scenario I start up a few docker containers each on it's own port, running the same software on a different infrastructure, like:

- Linux, Apache 2.x, PHP 5.x, MySQL 4.x
- Linux, Apache 2.x, PHP 5.x, MySQL 5.x
- Linux, Apache 2.x, PHP 7.x, MySQL 4.x *(if even possible)*
- Linux, Apache 2.x, PHP 7.x, MySQL 5.x
- Linux, Apache 2.x, PHP 5.x, SQLite
- Linux, Apache 2.x, PHP 7.x, SQLite

Preferably with a lightweight Linux distro such as Arch or Alpine.

*I just finished some successful testing with Ubuntu as a distro but before I go into scripting all these Docker images myself I wondered if there is no easier solution to get this up and running.*

**Is there an easier way to test PHP source-code on multi-platforms using Docker images?**

Comment: And what is the way you are using?

Comment: I currently run Docker on Windows host OS. I made a docker file `FROM ubuntu:latest` and `COPY` for copying the PHP files, and then a whole load of commands after `RUN` using `apt --yes -q` et cetera in order to install all necessary packages. It works, but is not ideal, since I don't really feel like scripting all Docker images like this. I feel like there should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Are you installing php and mysql together in the same container?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to use this docker containers as stand-alone test-containers. Alternatively I could connect to different database containers. And setup only different containers for the PHP and SQL versions.

Comment: Multiple process per container is a well known anti-pattern. In docker each container should have one process. You can use docker-compose to wire all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can skip the process of build each environment. Altough you can use some pre-builted images from docker hub to speed up.

I'd create the following structure:

```
|-- test.sh
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- php5.X
|   `-- Dockerfile
|-- php7.X
    `-- Dockerfile
```

Inside each Dockerfile, if you need to customize them so much, you can use a base image and install everything you need.

Here is the tricky thing:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php${PHP_VERSION}/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This way you'll run different versions depending on the environment variables, so you can easily do this in your script:

**test.sh**

```
export MYSQL_VERSION=5.6
export PHP_VERSION=7.1

docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit

export MYSQL_VERSION=5.5
export PHP_VERSION=5.6

docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit

...
```

Comment: Ah, you got me on the right track with docker compose! Thanks a lot. I now have three containers running with different MySQL versions and four containers with different PHP versions. I connect from those PHP codebase to each of the three MySQL servers. So I can now test all combinations.